# How to non-destructively check in C++ that nothing in directory can be written/deleted

Tags: c++, filesystems

I would like to make sure a directory that a unit test is about to access has permissions that would stop that test from changing anything. In particular, it should not be allowed to modify, create, or delete files/subdirectories. There is too much data to copy to a temporary location.

I am aware of std::filesystem::permissions, but to use that I would still need to know who owns what file, who I am, and same again for groups. If the directory is empty, I would also need to know if I have write permission in the parent directory, and whether the sticky flag is set. Then I would probably have the answer. It still assumes I want to run under some flavour of Unix (true as it happens), and also that no-one is modifying anything in parallel (fine for now).

I guess a fallback in the absence of a general cross-platform solution would be to just check that I don't own the directory and group/other permissions are off. It would not be bullet-proof, but it would probably be safe enough for my purposes. Is there a better way?

Comment: Pretty OS-dependent.

Comment: I see that "Pretty" and raise you a "Very."

Comment: It  really sounds like something a shell script should check before the script runs the test(s).

Comment: I'll take a shell-script answer then :-)

Comment: @NeilButterworth What if the shell script passes and immediately after (but before the unit test is running) the directory becomes not writeable? ok, worst case but... sh*t happens

Comment: @roalz the same could happen with the C++ program

Comment: @NeilButterworth Right, with a (much) smaller time interval between check and operate if all done in C++, but still not atomic ;-)